# Modify a JSON string

Tags: c#, json, string

I have a string in JSON format as follows

```
string jsonStr = "{"Type":1, "Id":1000,"Date":null,"Group": "Admin","Country":"India","Type":1}";
```

I want to modify this string so that Id attribute should always be the first. The order of attributes matters.
Is there any way I can modify this string.

I tried searching google but did not find appropriate solution.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I also tried to deserialize object using

```
 object yourOjbect = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(jsonStr);
```

But here also the "type" attribute comes first. I dont find any way to move the attributes within this deserialized object

Comment: *"The order of attributes matters."* Not in JSON, it doesn't. *"An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs."* - http://json.org *(my emphasis)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes you are correct. But the string I want should be in that order only, as I am comparing it with another string.

Comment: Do you need to compare two json objects?

Comment: @faridbekran No, I want to compare two strings

Comment: Why do you want to compar Strings instead Objects?

Comment: @OscarVicentePerez I have some string values in Database(in JSON format) where Id attribute is the first one. Now I have a new string jsonStr where type attribute is first one. When I compare jsonStr with string in Database, it returns false (obviously). To get it return true, I want to modify it so it should match the one in database.

Comment: If you do not want to parse json and convert to json object, this question is not a json related question anymore. You just want to compare two strings.

Comment: You can use Json.NET to convert it into a true object and use an overriden Equals to compare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. Use the JsonProperty attribute, property Order.
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyOrder.htm.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Microsoft DN, did this help? Do you need any sample to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to manipulate the order of the outputted JSON and comparing strings, I would transform both JSON strings that you want to compare, into objects and then perform your comparison. You could then compare individual properties or entire objects with something like the following:

```
void CompareJSON()
{
    string json = @"{""Type"":1, ""Id"":1000,""Date"":null,""Group"": ""Admin"",""Country"":""India"",""Type"":1}";
    string jsonToCompare = "JSON TO COMPARE";

    MyObject myJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
    MyObject myJsonObjectToCompare = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonToCompare);

    if (myJsonObject.Id == myJsonObjectToCompare.Id)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Please note that this example is carried out using the `Newtonsoft.JSON` library. More information on the library can be found [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Answer (score -1):

Just make your JSON into a c# class with Id first and then serialize it again if that is what you need.  You do know that you have "Type" twice in the JSON string? In this solution it will get "fixed" so you only have it once as it should be. But if your string really is with two Type this wont work since the strings will be incorrect. If they really are like that you need to do some ugly string manipulation to fix the order but i hope the first string is incorrect only here and not in your code.

```
    private void Test() {
        string json = @"{""Type"":1, ""Id"":1000,""Date"":null,""Group"": ""Admin"",""Country"":""India"",""Type"":1}";

        JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        MyJsonObject myJsonObject = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyJsonObject>(json);

        string s = jsonSerializer.Serialize(myJsonObject);
        //Returns: {"Id":1000,"Type":1,"Date":null,"Group":"Admin","Country":"India"}
    }


class MyJsonObject {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```